# Query Inserting repeated rows

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will insert a Disposition-Code and Disposition-Desc into my table ONLY if the Disposition-Code does not exist. I currently have this, but for some reason it is inserting all the dispositions of all my records into my disposition table. My goal is to have a dispositions table with all the UNIQUE DISPOSITIONS.

```
INSERT INTO TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorDispositions   ([DISPOSITION-CODE], [DISPOSITION-DESC]) 
SELECT t1.[DISPOSITION-CODE], t1.[DISPOSITION-DESC]   
FROM TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorPublicRecords t1  
WHERE t1.[DISPOSITION-CODE] NOT IN (SELECT [DISPOSITION-CODE] FROM TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorDispositions)
```

This block of code is inserting every disposition of every record into my new table. So instead of having a table with 30 dispositions, I have a table the size of my records table. Lets say I have a disposition code of 619 that has already been inserted into my table. I want the query to NOT INSERT this disposition again.

Does any one have any insight of how to do this?

Comment: use a unique constraint so you don't insert duplicate records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this query. Note the `DISTINCT` constraint on select

```
INSERT INTO 
 TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorDispositions   
 (
  [DISPOSITION-CODE], 
  [DISPOSITION-DESC]
 ) 
SELECT DISTINCT
 [DISPOSITION-CODE], 
 [DISPOSITION-DESC]   
FROM 
 TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorPublicRecords
WHERE [DISPOSITION-CODE] NOT IN 
(
 SELECT 
  DISTINCT [DISPOSITION-CODE] 
 FROM 
 TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorDispositions
)
```

Comment: This is the answer I was going to post. To expand: the `DISTINCT` is appropriate here because if you have multiple copies of the same code in `TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorDispositions`, then *all* of them will satisfy the `WHERE` clause in the query from the question, and so of course you'll get duplicate entries.

Comment: DUDE!!! YOU ARE DA REAL MVP! Thank you this query inserted 253 rows into my table, before the query was inserting over 1 million. Thanks for your help @DhruvJoshi

Answer (score -2):

Create an index in TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorDispositions to prevent duplicate values of disposition code. 
The duplicate index error message can be toggled to a warning message and it's all good. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869.aspx

Comment: @bjones indeed. Create an index.

Comment: @nicomp So add a unique identifier in my dispositions table?

Comment: This doesn't address why the OP's query isn't doing what he wants it to do. All your suggestion will do is turn a query that produces the wrong result into a query that produces an error.

Comment: @JoeFarrell Nope. It fixes the problem. But thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @nicomp, I suggest you try it yourself and see. Create the tables from the question, load them with data such that the OP's query will insert duplicate records, then create your unique index and run the query. You'll receive the following error message: `Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorDispositions' with unique index '[IndexName]'. The duplicate key value is ([Value]).` I'm not saying that a unique constraint is a bad idea, but adding it doesn't fix the real problem, which is the original query.

Comment: @JoeFarrell No, my solution works just fine. What you don't know is that the error message can be toggled to a warning message and it's all good. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869.aspx

Comment: @nicomp: You're right, I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out. Don't you think that might have been a useful bit of information to include in your answer?